# Using Android Intent, How Do I Open Files?

Tags: android, android-intent

When clicking on File Open, I have the following code:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
                intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
                intent.SetType("file/*.*");
                intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);   
                StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

This works. I can move from folder to folder and see the files in a list.

BUT the files are all grayed out, so they cannot be opened.

How can I make them openable? Of course the code would have to block some files (like binary file, applications etc.)

Thanks!!!

Comment: `SetType,("*/*");`

Comment: Remove the categories.

Comment: `the files are all grayed out, so they cannot be opened.` You mean they can not be selected.

Comment: Yes. I commented out the SetType("file/*.*") but no change. I can look through folders but cannot select a file.

Comment: Why dont you try the suggestions?

Comment: I just did and THANKS!!! That works.

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
                    intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
                    //intent.SetType("file/*.*");
                    intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);  
                    StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);

Comment: Just to say it again: THANK YOU!!!!